# Dell inspiron 17R-7720 numeric keyboard is locked

Tags: numlock

The numeric keyboard is locked.
What function key unlocks this and what picture?
Most of the online searches the function keys have different uses to mine.
I know what <kbd>F2</kbd> does and it is different to what I have read.

Comment: Maybe it's `Caps Lock`

Comment: Try pressing the fn key *and* F2 at once? Also I can't find a clear picture of the keyboard on that model so a clear photo of the keyboard layout would help so much